# Проблема с компиляцией OpenHD на OrangePI

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, orange-pi

Я скачал с github код openhd. Установил компилятор, cmake и ninja-bilder. Запустил файл ild_cmake.sh и мне выдалась ошибка.

```
CMake Error at ohd_common/CMakeLists.txt:21 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /home/orangepi/Desktop/12/OpenHD-2.4.0/OpenHD/ohd_common/lib/spdlog

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at ohd_common/CMakeLists.txt:26 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /home/orangepi/Desktop/12/OpenHD-2.4.0/OpenHD/ohd_common/lib/json

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR filesystem)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  ohd_common/CMakeLists.txt:33 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/orangepi/Desktop/12/OpenHD-2.4.0/OpenHD/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Я так понял что ему не хватает файлов, но где мне их найти или собрать?

Comment: Где брали исходники? Запустите git submodule update init